# How can I scale a div as large as possible, keeping the aspect ratio and not exceeding the parent?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a fixed aspect-ratio that scales larger, if the wrapper becomes larger.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class = "aspect_ratio_3-2">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.aspect_ratio_3-2 {
 width:100%;
 background: rgba(255,0,0,0.8);
}
.aspect_ratio_3-2:after{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    padding-top: 50%;
}
.wrapper{
    width: 20%;
    height: 90%;
    background: black;
}
```

You can see it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwdp8dpx/)

If the aspect ratio of the wrapper is bigger than the aspect ratio of the div, the div exceeds the wrapper (too high).

I'm searching for a CSS only method to scale the div as large as possible, without exceeding the wrapper. The width and height of the wrapper is not known!

Is there something similar to

```
background-size: contain
```

just for divs? Solving this problem with javascript is quite easy, but I want to do it with css only.

Comment: I do not think this exists without the use of javascript.

Comment: Styles are mostly generic, across all sorts of HTML elements.  I don't see anything in the CSS specs that would keep `background-size:contain` from being applicable to a div.  Have you actually tried it (in, say, your `.aspect_ratio_3-2` style-details)?  Also, a separate thing, the name "aspect_ratio_3-2" may not be entirely valid; try "aspect_ratio_3_2"